# Conditional middleware behavior via handler

Tags: http, go, handler, middleware

I am trying to implement conditional middleware behavior after a handler call.

I've looked into contexts and was able to alter/use them as flags, passing data INTO the handler from the middleware but not FROM the handler to middleware. The method signatures do not allow for return values.

This is a quick writeup of what I am working with:

```golang
func Reporter(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        // conditionally check if err != nil here and log
    })
}

func appRoutes(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(Reporter)
    r.Get("/", ListApplications)
}

func ListApplications(w http.ResponseWriter, , r *http.Request) {
    apps, err := fetchApps()
    if err != nil {
        render.Render(w, r, ErrorStructRenderer(err))
        return
    }
    render.Respond(w, r, apps)
}
```

Comment: You can't with that type of middleware. You could if your handlers used a non-standard signature to return an error (which means they would only work with your middleware). Or you could just handle your errors in your handlers.

Comment: Just as you can pass data into the handler by storing it in the context, so you can have the handler store the error in the context and have the middleware look for it after the handler exits. If you've done that but it didn't work for you can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: @mkopriva I was unsure of how to get context from the handler back to the middleware. To get from middleware to handler I substituted with this `next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), ContextKey, "THIS IS A VALUE FROM MIDDLEWARE")))` and then in the handler I was able to access with: `r.Context().Value(ContextKey).(string)`

Comment: @sharklasers right, I forgot about the shallow copy that `WithContext` returns which makes it a little bit different to do from handler to middleware, but it's possible, although maybe not idiomatic. When you call `WithContext` in the handler you save the result in a new variable, say `r2`, then you use that to update the pointer of the original request like so `*r = *r2`, now when the handler exists the middleware can access the context of `r2` using the `r` variable.